# Docker Containers in a ubuntu server vm have no access to shared folders

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, permissions, docker

I was setting up a media server in ubuntu server running inside a vm. I installed docker in it and set up everything from sonarr, radarr, torrent client,plex, etc and  after installing everything i realized that plex,sonarr,radarr,etc cant even see my shared folder which is present in my vm as `/media/sf_Media`. so what steps must i take so that plex, sonarr, radarr can see my folder as well as all folders within it?

sorry i am new to linux and have been using it only for the last 5 months so please bear with me. Also sorry for my english as its not my primary language

P.S. my host is windows 7 ultimate( if that's important)

EDIT: I used `sudo chmod -R 775 /media` and it showed the directories in `/media` including `sf_Media` in plex but once I click sf_Media folder in plex it shows up to be empty. I tried `sudo chmod -R 775 /media/sf_Media` too but that didnt work out.

SO It seems my own user have access to `/media/sf_Media/` and its sub directories ( because i can use `ls /media/sf_Media` to show the contents without sudo) but the docker containers doesn't. Now that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bind-mount to add the shared directory to the container

```
docker run -v /media/thefolder:/path/in/the/container {image}
```